# How to bind angular 4 component to a page without creating(defining) a template url

Tags: angular

Is there any possibility to create a component without defining template url?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample-page',
    templateUrl: ''
})
export class AppComponent { ...}
```

I want to bind a component to existing ASP.NET page without writing the tag.

```
<sample-page></sample-page>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this?

Comment: without selector how will you identify the component?

Comment: Withour selector your component will get default `ng-component` selector. You can bind that component to any element on your page but you have to define template

Comment: What does "to a page" mean exactly? You can use attribute selectors: `<td myTableCell>...</td>` with `@Component({ selector: 'myTableCell'})` and if you don't want a `templateUrl`, you can just use a directive - which is a component without a template.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks! That's what i meant. Sorry for poor or wrong explaining.

Comment: I would keep in mind it is not angularjs

Comment: @yurzui thank you too!

Comment: @Buckethead The root component has to be a component (which can have an attribute selector AFAIR), directives can only be used within other components (not outside of an Angular application anywhere on an HTML page)